# Would pro wrestling be considered on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

**Would pro wrestling (WWE, TNA, etc.) be considered on topic?**

When I say "pro wrestling" here, I am specifically talking about the ["entertainment form."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional_wrestling)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Over two years after this question was asked, another question was asked about WWE storylines: [Are WWE storyline questions on-topic here?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/556/are-wwe-storyline-questions-on-topic-here?lq=1)

In short, [this answer](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/558) summarized how the community felt about WWE storyline questions, but also provided insight for this question.

> If the question is about the story line part (for example why a feud
>   developed) then this question is off topic for Sports SE (but on topic at Movies SE). However, **if
>   the question is about the sport part of wrestling (e.g. What's the
>   difference between a German suplex and a drop suplex?) then that would
>   be considered on topic for Sports SE.**

Comment: I assume questions about e.g. backstage politics (why did XXX refuse to participate in YYY match? Why does WWE no longer promote ZZZ matches/title/etc?) would also be off-topic here?

Comment: I would consider that related to the "storyline" part of pro wrestling, and thus, off topic.

Answer (score 10):

I think that overall, this will be a question that is better served *after* a few of these have been asked so that we can sort of test question quality and topicality.

I don't know what a *good* pro wrestling question looks like at this point? Is one going to ask about results? (probably not really constructive as they should be easily googleable) Is one going to ask about moves? (probably good) What about a question about real vs fake? fixed vs competitive?

So without knowing what wrestling questions are going to look like on this site, it would be hard to actually answer whether or not they are on topic.

Asked in a vacuum I'd hesitantly say yes, but without seeing one or two come through I can't say for sure how I really feel.

Comment: This is a fair assessment. Thanks.

Comment: I have a fair number of questions about pro wrestling, I didn't think they'd be welcome here but I'm willing to become a test case :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not intimately familiar with pro wrestling but I was under the impression that a lot of it was for entertainment purposes, i.e. the winner is known beforehand to the organizers and that a lot of the moves, etc, are for show.

If that is the case, I'd argue that those leagues that that applies to would be off-topic as it isn't really a sport.  You can't analyze a move or results or other if the result is predetermined.  For those leagues I'd suggest [TV.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) would be a better location.

If there are legit leagues out there, then questions about those would be on-topic.

Comment: Good points... My initial thought was **no** because of "soap drama" (entertainment) purposes. As you bring up, if there are legit pro wrestling leagues out there, would they be in the same category with MMA and UFC?

Comment: I'm not sure we even need to distinguish based on legitimacy. But again, any decision without actually seeing a couple of these questions is kinda silly.

Comment: are there any professional wrestling promotions left that *aren't* worked? I know there was an attempt to resurrect 1920s-era catch wrestling a few years back but I thought it folded. huh. Maybe that's a good question for the main site...