# Are WWE storyline questions on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I'm an active user over at the [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) site. We've had [a question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/27506/reason-behind-the-feud-between-wwes-wyatt-family-members) recently which has stirred up a fair bit of debate, surrounding a *storyline on WWE*.

Whilst I myself answered it on the site, I started [a Meta discussion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/is-a-question-on-wwe-on-topic) to discuss how on topic it was (with mixed views/low participation so far). Despite the fact it's obviously not a true *sport*, it just doesn't (in my view) feel like a good fit for us, as we primarily deal in typical movies and television series. I have argued that shows like NBC's Sunday Night Football are billed as episodic - if someone asked a question about something a presenter did on a particular episode, I'd certainly not consider it on-topic.

So, bearing all this in mind: **would a question on a WWE storyline be welcome on this site?** (in which case we could migrate over future questions) Or would you consider it off-topic and want to send it straight back our way?

Comment: Reference: http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/206/would-pro-wrestling-be-considered-on-topic

Comment: @edmastermind29: Thanks. I saw that question but noticed the top answer was "wait and see". Hopefully we can get some clarification on this now (given the sample question).

Comment: Same with the definition of "true sport" on Sports SE...mainly because users get unfavorable votes/comments due to different opinions on what users consider to be sports and not. http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/503/guideline-for-on-topic-questions-on-sports-se-regarding-activities#comment1203_555

Comment: Back on topic, we had a WWE question on Kane's mask...and it wasn't taken poorly. So, I guess I'm saying "wait and see" again. http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5286/why-does-kane-wear-a-mask-one-week-and-the-next-not

Comment: With 5 upvotes with no objection, it looks like we're saying WWE ***storyline*** questions are off topic on Sports SE. FYI so you can shore things up at Movies & TV.

Answer (score 13):

WWE *storyline* questions should be off topic.

I agree with the answer suggested by **System Down** on the [Movies & TV meta](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/is-a-question-on-wwe-on-topic), that we should differentiate between the story part and sport part of pro-wrestling. I think that differention would serve both sites well. To me, the story part is about writing, scripting and plotting, as would be done for soap operas and other serial TV shows, and experts about this are more likely to be found on the TV & Movies site. I hope that the sports part of pro-wrestling could be answered by someone with wrestling experience on this site.

To rephrase **System Down**'s answer from a sports SE perspective:

> if the question is about the story line part (for example why a feud developed) then this question is off topic for Sports SE. However, if the
>   question is about the sport part of wrestling (e.g. What's the
>   difference between a German suplex and a drop suplex?) then that would
>   be considered on topic for Sports SE.

Comment: I endorse this perspective as I had similar thoughts.

Comment: +1 This makes more sense than my answer.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not personally a fan of WWE, but I would call it on-topic and would not vote to close a good question about WWE.

I say, "just bring it."

[image]

Comment: Hey, it's that actor guy.

Comment: @MichaelMyers I thought he was a cook...he always asks if we smell what he's cooking...